# Unable to split the list of files

Tags: jenkins, groovy, cloudbees

I am having list of files in a directory.
For Ex:

sample1.properties
sample2.properties
sample3.properties

I am trying to use the groovy code to push these values in the Jenkins Active Choices parameter. How can I populate this list without ".properties" at the end. My list of Active choices parameters needs to be like this:

sample1
sample2
sample3

Code I am using is:

```
def reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))
def results = new JsonSlurper().parseText(reader.getText());
reader.close()
data= results.tree.path
data.each { 
it -> if(it.endsWith(".properties"))
choices.push(it.replace("/","") )
}
choices=choices.sort()
choices.add(0,"SELECT")
return choices
```

Comment: Could you post the sample of what `results.tree.path` contains, please?

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing the .properties part will not work?

```
choices.push(it.replace("/","").replace(".properties", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption regarding your `results.tree.path` content is correct, then you should probably use something like that:

```
def data = [
    'some/complex/path/sample1.properties',
    'some/complex/path/some_irrelevant_file.txt',
    'some/complex/path/sample2.properties',
    'some/complex/path/sample3.properties'
]

data.findAll { it.endsWith('.properties') }
    .collect { it.split('/').last().replace('.properties', '') }
    .each { println it }
```

so, in your case, you need to do:

```
results.tree.path.findAll { it.endsWith('.properties') }
    .collect { it.split('/').last().replace('.properties', '') }
    .each { choices.push(it) }
```